# Gradle Module Metadata: how to prevent dependency constraint with NULL version

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm using Gradle 6.9.2 and I noticed that there is an opportunity to define a dependency constraint without any version, like

```
dependencies {
    constraints {
        implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress'
     }
 }
```

The generated .module file will have NULL version:

```
"dependencyConstraints": [
    {
      "group": "org.apache.commons",
      "module": "commons-compress"
    }
```

If we try to add such kind of lib (with NULL version for dep constraint), our build will fail

```
  Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve {lib_with_incorrect_dep_constraint}.
  Required by:
     project {project-name}
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

A couple of questions:

1. Is there any sense in having dependency constraint without any version?
2. Is there any way to enable any kind of validation before publishing such libs?
3. Is there any way to disable reading dependency constraint section from dependency lib?

Answer (score 0):

The validation doesn't work properly in Gradle  https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/20791
WIll be fixed in 6.9.3 and 7.5